# I want to launch new Activity when the Item on Navigation Drawer is click using if statement

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer and if I click each Items the new activity will be display. I want to use an if statement.

**Part of MainActivity.java**

```
public static class ItemFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_ITEM_NUMBER = "item_number";

public ItemFragment() {
// Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, container, false);
int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_ITEM_NUMBER);
String item = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.item_array)[i];

//I want to enter the code here using if statement for each Item to open NewActivity 

return rootView;
}
}
```

**String.xml**

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Navigation Drawer Example</string>
<string-array name="item_array">
    <item>Item 1</item>
    <item>Item 2</item>
    <item>Item 3</item>
    <item>Item 4</item>
    <item>Item 5</item>
    <item>Item 6</item>
    <item>Item 7</item>
    <item>Item 8</item>
</string-array>
<string name="drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
```

I am new to android and 
thank you for ur help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are official android docs that will help get you going with such basic tasks. See [Creating a Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). They use Fragments but it's essentally the same stuff with activities.

Comment: add tag and layout change

Answer (score 0):

okay first populate your items in navigation drawer using `listView` . Then add `onItemClickListener` to that `listview` from which you will be able to get the position. Inside that `onItemClickListener`() method you can use if statement

```
if(position == 0)
{
//do something for first item in your list
}
```